# Java date/calendar ignoring time zone

Tags: java, date, calendar

How to ignore timezone in dates? I mean I seted some jsf input with 8:54 with format HH:mm, and in setter I am getting 9:54, i Think that is because of time zone GMT+1. How to convert this date to ignore time zone? How to convert it when i dont know from which time zone I am using it.

code, setter of time picker input:

```
public void setDateTest(Date hmm){
    if (hmm!=null){
        int a = hmm.getHours();
        int b = hmm.getMinutes();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);
        cal.setTime(hmm);

        int a2 = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int c2 = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int b2 = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could we see the code where you are getting/parsing the 8:54 date, and where you're producing the 9:54 date?

Comment: Code added. It is just setter of date component. Here thoose a b c variables values are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using java.util.Calendar (probably you are), Hour index is in range between 0-11

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR

so if you are giving 8 for Calendar.HOUR, this is actually 9. This might be the cause. Just an opinion...

Comment: ye maybe it is like u said, but it is wird that both for 9AM return 10. So Hour ignore time zones?

Comment: That's not right. `Calendar.HOUR` just uses 0 to represent noon and midnight. 10 AM would be 10.